# Fixed footer in viewport using bootstrap/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to replicate the effect of the footer from this website:

http://www.terradatbroker.com

In essence what it does is like the image at the top, the image stays fixed while the viewport of the div or section scrolls. I'd like the same with a div or footer block filled with content so that when reaching the footer, the lower part of the footer is revealed first, letting the content div slide upward while scrolling down. I hope this describes it clearly.
Here's what I've got so far:

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="row content-filler">
    Content 1
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <h1 class="">Footer</h1>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS snippet:

```
  footer {
      background-color: #444;
      min-height: 350px;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;

      z-index: 1;
  }
  .footer {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: #444;
      position:fixed;
      top: 800px;
      z-index: 1;
  }
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the full source code:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39204/

I've searched many bootstrap themes but I couldn't find one that does this effect. I've also looked at the css but I suspect it may be done using javascript, which is minified and unreadable. Can anyone shed some light on how this is done?

Comment: This is just a fixed footer, that has the main content scrolling “above” it. This doesn’t need any JavaScript (well, if you know the height of the footer; if it is dynamic, you might want to use JS to measure how much of a margin/padding is needed below the main content to give enough space to show the full footer content.)

Comment: http://www.terradatbroker.com. it uses the JS for fancy scroll not for footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39205/ 
Footer is **fixed** with `bottom:0`
The last div.row has a margin-bottom, for give space to the footer.
Hope it helps, cheers.